# Can I Pass a URL variable to an IFrame using PHP?

Tags: php, iframe

I've not used PHP much (or at all) before, and I have the following code:

```
<?php
$val = $_GET['ID'];
echo "<iframe src='sitename.com.au/directory/app/pagename.cfm?memberid='$val'    width='100%' scrolling='vertical'></iframe>";
?>
```

I think that should be ok to take a URL variable and pass it to an Iframe url...my issue is that when I hit the page this is on instead of it being:

```
http://sitename.com/whats-on?ID=2
```

its

```
http://sitename.com/whats-on/?ID=2
```

I don't know where that slash before /?ID is coming from - but I believe it is causing my problem - the iframe displaying a page not found message.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iFrames just take a url - and parameters can be embedded in urls just fine.

The problem, if I understand the question clearly, is that you're mixing up your quotes:

```
 echo "<iframe src='sitename.com.au/directory/app/pagename.cfm?memberid='$val'
        width='100%' scrolling='vertical'></iframe>";
```

will be outputted as

```
 <iframe src='sitename.com.au/directory/app/pagename.cfm?memberid=' 21254545' 
  width='100%' scrolling='vertical'></iframe>
```

where 21254545  is an attribute of the iframe instead of part of the url.

Assuming that you don't actually need the quotes in the url, change the echo line to:

```
echo "<iframe src='sitename.com.au/directory/app/pagename.cfm?memberid=$val' width='100%' scrolling='vertical'></iframe>";
```

And it should work.

Comment: Thanks MackieChan! - appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

- Add **http://**  before sitename.com.au/
- Change memberid='$val'  to **memberid=$val'**  [remove that *single quote* on left of $val]

```
<?php
   $val = $_GET['ID'];
   echo "<iframe src='sitename.com.au/directory/app/pagename.cfm?memberid=$val' width='100%' scrolling='vertical'></iframe>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the

```
echo "<iframe src='sitename.com.au/directory/app/pagename.cfm?memberid=$val' width='100%' scrolling='vertical'></iframe>";
```

doesn't work anymore. You have to add the variable like this

```
 echo "<iframe src='sitename.com.au/directory/app/pagename.cfm?memberid=".$val."' width='100%' scrolling='vertical'></iframe>";
```

Since the anwser was from 2012... maybe PHP patched it to be used like that now.